# java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: oracle/apps/fnd/ext/common/AppsRequestWrapper$WrapperException

Tags: oracle-adf

I'm trying to integrate ADF with EBS.
Following the Link:
http://mistech.pixnet.net/blog/post/365709524-adf-%E6%95%B4%E5%90%88%E6%96%BC-%28-integrate-%29-oracle-ebs-r12
But getting the error:

```
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: oracle.apps.fnd.ext.common.AppsRequestWrapper$WrapperException
```

Answer (score 0):

Did you copy and paste the .java file into the package? If yes then delete the file and recreate it from JDeveloper

Comment: No, I made file from Jdeveloper. Repeat the process but not able to achieve.